# What do you do when you edit a question to make it clearer, and the person re-edits it back?

Tags: discussion

I edited this:

[How do I create a UIImageView using only code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546102/xcode-4-creating-image-view-only-with-code)

Because it made the usual mistake of saying the problem was an Xcode problem, when they really had a Cocoa/Interface Builder issue.

The edit was accepted by the moderators, then the person edited it to change it back to Xcode. Do I re-edit it? Or flag it somehow?

Comment: As an aside, suggested edits aren't *necessarily* accepted by moderators, they can be accepted by any two community members with the privilege to approve / reject edits. Since there are badges associated with edit volume, you shouldn't necessarily tie the fact that your edit was approved with the fact that it was absolutely 100% correct. It is likely that only the OP can really know for sure.

Comment: @AaronBertrand [In this case](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/321364), it actually was accepted by a moderator (Bill the Lizard) =)

Comment: Yours was better, I clicked Rollback for you.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Rollback war!

Comment: @jadarnel27: flagged, many thanks. In these situations it is tempting to add "WHEN I SAY HILSHIRE YOU SAY FARMS, HILSHIRE!" to the post such that it hits CW status at the 10th edit. No more rep for you, because you'd rather your post be bad.

Comment: @sixlettervariables FARMS!

Comment: @Almo - If you improve a post and the OP doesn't like it, just leave it at that. There is a million other posts that also need an edit. Try one of those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes this can be caused by the original author building an edit while you are working on yours. If their edit is more substantial, it will likely win, and there is no "smart merge" of the two edits. Instead of getting into an edit war, I suggest leaving a comment asking why they insist on using one term when clearly it's about the other. It's quite possible they just didn't see your edit because they overlapped. It's also possible they have a reason for using the term they are using, and it may or may not be valid. More effective to discuss those in comments than trying to force your opinion using continuous edits.

Comment: -1, obviously you're supposed to get into a rollback war.

Comment: -1, forgot to mention that you are morally obligated to go into their history and downvote every single one of their answers and questions.

Comment: You guys be crazy

Comment: Ah, side-effects may include suspension, account deletion for misuse of voting privileges, and/or irritable bowel syndrome.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You sound just like my therapist.  And my case-worker.  And my parole officer.

Comment: @jadarnel27 as long as those aren't the same person. Or your alter personalities.

Answer (score 4):

Retagging or editing cocoa / cocoa-touch questions away from Xcode is like trying to empty an ocean with a teaspoon. A tiny, tiny teaspoon. And a big, big ocean. And the teaspoon has only a handle.

They're just synonymous in so many people's minds, I'd learn to live with it if I were you. In the general case, unless you're convinced you're really adding value (I dont think your editing here has made the question *much* better) I'd also give up on it, if the OP is that determined, you're wasting your time.

Comment: Good points4321

Comment: I know it's a hopeless cause, but I still try to edit out Xcode references in non-IDE- or compiler-related questions. Every time you do this, you help keep the site just a little cleaner. We might not be able to solve the problem, but at least we can do a little something for it.

Comment: He was pretty determined.